# Grothendieck Universes: Atoms

Tags: set-theory, definition

I'm very much beginner in set theory; my apologize for mistakes.

Grothendieck universe:
$$\forall X(X\in \mathcal{U}\Rightarrow\mathcal{P}(X)\in U\}$$
$$\forall X\forall x(x\in X\in\mathcal{U}\Rightarrow x\in\mathcal{U})$$
$$\forall X\forall Y(X,Y\in\mathcal{U}\Rightarrow\{X,Y\}\in\mathcal{U})$$
And ...:
$$\forall \Lambda\forall X_{\lambda\in\Lambda}(\Lambda\in\mathcal{U}:\ldots)$$
*(I'll extend this later!)*

Doesn't the empty collection constitute a Grothendieck universe?

May a Grothendieck universe contain any atoms apart the empty set?
$$X=\{x\}:\quad X\in U\implies x\in U$$
In that case how is the power set to be understood?
$$X=\{x\}:\quad x\in U\implies \mathcal{P}(x)\in U$$
Does set theory in general distinguish atoms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Doesn't the empty collection constitute a Grothendieck universe?

See [Grothendieck universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grothendieck_universe) :

> There are two simple examples of Grothendieck universes:
>
> > The empty set, and
> >
> > The set of all hereditarily finite sets $V_{\omega}$.

---

> Does set theory in general distinguish atoms?

For set theory, due to extensionality, all "objects" without elements are equal; thus, there is only one: the empty set.

In order to allow for atoms (or [urelements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urelement#Urelements_in_set_theory), as in the original [Zermelo's axiomatization](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/zermelo-set-theory/)), we have to use a "two-sorted" language with a primitive predicate $U$ such that $Ux$ is intended to mean “$x$ is an *urelement*” (therefore $¬Ux$ will mean “$x$ is a *set*”).

In this way, we have to reformulate the [Extensionality Axiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_extensionality) as :

> $$¬U(A) ∧ ¬U(B) → [(∀x)(x ∈ A ↔ x ∈ B) → A = B].$$

See :

- George Tourlakis, [Lectures in Logic and Set Theory. Volume 2 : Set Theory](https://books.google.it/books?id=nparMXao59QC&pg=PA99) (2003), page 99.

---

Please, note that $X=\{ x \}$ is not an atom, but a [singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_(mathematics)) : e.g. $\emptyset \ne \{ \emptyset \}$

There is no [power set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set) for an *atom*: an atom has no elements and thus no subset, while the power set of a *singleton* $X=\{ x \}$ has two elements : $\emptyset$ and $\{ x \}$.

Comment: So ZFC does not allow urelements other than the empty set, i.e. it is invalid to say $x\neq y$ for urelements $x,y\in\mathcal{U}$?

Comment: @Freeze_S -  standard expositions of the canonical axiomatic set theories ZF and [ZFC](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/set-theory/index.html#AxiZFC) have no urelements; the original [Zermelo](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/zermelo-set-theory/)'s version of 1908 included urelements. But see [Suppes](https://books.google.it/books?id=skTCAgAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover) for a modern version with urelements. 1//2

Comment: There are well-known axiomatizations of set theory that do use urelements : [Kripke–Platek set theory with urelements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kripke%E2%80%93Platek_set_theory_with_urelements), and the variant of [Von Neumann–Bernays–Gödel set theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann%E2%80%93Bernays%E2%80%93G%C3%B6del_set_theory) of [Mendelson](https://books.google.it/books?id=ZO1p4QGspoYC&lpg=PP1&pg=PT309). 2/2

Comment: Nice, ok I think I got it now. Thanks alot also for the further links!!!